# Enter sudo password through python

Tags: python, passwords, sudo

I am making a python script that will not be running in the terminal and as it has to `sudo` multiple scripts I need to be able to enter the password from the script. What I mean is this: A program that I wrote and only I am going to use starts. It uses a gui box to ask for my `sudo` password. I give it to it, and then it enters it when needed. I get the textbox part downpath, but how do I enter the password into the `sudo` program from python?

Comment: I think what you mean is, how do you use sudo command in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

It works like this:

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Comment: Please read [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/155827): `Please note: Any method which involves putting your login password in plain text, in a command or in a file, is insecure and should NOT be used!`